# How to add different data attribute to random elements in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with Animate on Scroll and want to assign a different animation delay to random elements in an array (or even vs. odd), which are displayed as list items. Since you have to add/change the data attribute (e.g. `data-aos-delay="50"`), I'm not sure how best to do this so that half the list items have a different delay time. Thanks so much!

[AOS on GitHub](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)

```
var words = ["Superheroes", "supervillains", "aliens", "monsters", "wizards", "warriors", "witches", "barbarians", "creatures", "robots", "cyborgs", "droids", "time travelers", "spaceships", "star fighters "]

function wordsLoad() {
// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}
words = shuffle(words);

//create HTML for each word
function createWord(word) {
    return '<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos="slide-up">' + word + '</li>';
}
//add words HTML to page
function generateWords() {
    const group = document.querySelector('.products');//.products of class of <ul>
    const wordHTML = words.map(function(word) {
        return createWord(word);
    });
    group.innerHTML = wordHTML.join('');
}
generateWords();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
wordsLoad();
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...are you saying that in `<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos="slide-up">` you want to add an attribute `data-aos-delay` with a random number?

Comment: I want to add `data-aos-delay` to all elements, but every other with a different number such as 
`<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos="slide-up" data-aos-delay="50">star fighters </li>
<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos="slide-up" data-aos-delay="100">aliens</li>
<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos="slide-up" data-aos-delay="50">warriors</li>`
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about adding data dynamically to the html strings you are generating, [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can help. Assuming you just want to alternate between two different delay values, you could try this:

```
function createWord(word, delay) {
    // using a template literal will enable string interpolation.
    // note the use of backticks (instead of single quotes):
    return `<li class="text-uppercase" data-aos-delay="${delay}" data-aos="slide-up">${word}</li>`;
}

function generateWords() {
    const group = document.querySelector('.products');

    const delayValues = [50, 100];
    const wordHTML = words.map(function(word, idx) {
        const delay = delayValues[idx % 2]; // alternate delay values for even vs odd words
        return createWord(word, delay);
    });
    group.innerHTML = wordHTML.join('');
}
```

Comment: I got this to work. Thanks! I've only been learning JS for about 9 months now so really appreciate the extra help.

Comment: Sure thing! Wanna accept this as the answer if it worked? :)